# Github actions failing after upgrading to node v20

Tags: github-actions, supabase

I'm trying to create a github workflow for my repo that is using supabase edge functions. The error I'm receiving is: `Node.js 16 actions are deprecated. Please update the following actions to use Node.js 20: actions/checkout@v3, actions/setup-node@v3. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2023-09-22-github-actions-transitioning-from-node-16-to-node-20/`.

I haven't set up a workflow before but I believe my workflow file is written correctly? I could be missing something really simple but haven't been able to find out what the issue is even after adding a specific version of node.

```
# .github/workflows/deploy-supabase-functions.yml
name: Deploy Supabase Functions

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      SUPABASE_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SUPABASE_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      PROJECT_ID: ***

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js 20.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 20.x

      - uses: supabase/setup-cli@v1
        with:
          version: latest

      - run: supabase functions deploy --project-ref ***
```

Comment: _"Ensure your workflows use the latest versions of actions that are running on Node 20."_ - `actions/checkout@v3` and `actions/setup-node@v3` are not, hence the warning.

Answer (score 6):

Your workflow is written fine -- the deprecation notice regarding node versions is with respect to the version of node that an action you're using is relying on. It has nothing at all to do with the version of node installed on the runner (unless you're self-hosting which you aren't), *or that you're installing with the setup-node action*.

If you have a look at [the notice it's linking you to](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-09-22-github-actions-transitioning-from-node-16-to-node-20/) you'll see that "for users of actions" links you to [an example of how to pick what version of an action you're running](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-versioned-actions) -- if you aren't sure, the part after the `@` describes either a commit sha, a tag, or a branch name to pin to.

So in your `uses: actions/checkout@v3` you're pinning to tag `v3` of `actions/checkout`.

Or more specifically, tag `v3` of the contents of the `checkout` repo owned by the user `actions` (at the repository root because there's no subdirectory specified), as specified in the `actions.yml` file at that tag and location in that repo.

If we have a look at the other link in that notice, namely, [how to set the node runtime of a JS based action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runs-for-javascript-actions), we can see that the deprecation notice is with regards to the setting `runs.using` in the `actions.yml` file.

Knowing all those pieces, we can have a look at the actions you're using that you're getting those notices for.

[actions/checkout@v3::action.yml::runs.using](https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/v3/action.yml#L90) -- is `node16`. You'll need to update to `v4` to be using a version of the action that uses `node20`.

Keep in mind that tags can be reassigned (and often are, such as a `vX` typically pointing to the latest `vX.Y.Z`), so tags and branches aren't immutable pins. At the time of writing, `v3` pin in `actions/checkout` is the sha `f43a0e5ff2bd294095638e18286ca9a3d1956744` and `v4` is sha `b4ffde65f46336ab88eb53be808477a3936bae11`.

[actions/setup-node@v3::action.yml::runs.using](https://github.com/actions/setup-node/blob/v3/action.yml#L36) is also `node16`, with `v4` having the `node20` that you're after. At time of writing `v3` is `1a4442cacd436585916779262731d5b162bc6ec7` and `v4` is `60edb5dd545a775178f52524783378180af0d1f8`.

**Edit**

How to pick what version of an action to update to? If we have a look at [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) as an example, the broadest but not necessarily most accessible way of checking, is to navigate to the `action.yml`, and view the `blame` of the file, e.g. [actions/checkout@main blame](https://github.com/actions/checkout/blame/main/action.yml) and navigate to the line that specifies `using: nodeX` and continue going "blame prior" until it's no longer `node20`, at that point if you go back one page it should show you the first commit on the trunk branch that had `using: node20` e.g. we can see [this commit on actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout/commit/97a652b80035363df47baee5031ec8670b8878ac) was the one that set the `using:` field to `node20`, so theoretically any commit after that point should be fine to use.

However, although pinning an action to a specific sha is advised for security reasons, it's also advised to not just pick any old commit (unless you're confident you know what you're doing). The better option for finding what version tag to use is to browse the tags of the repo, which can be navigated between by clicking the button on the top left above the list of files in the root of the repo, which will give you the option to `Switch branches/tags`. Whilst it is possible for a repo to follow a pattern of diverging branches for major versions, and thus have a fix for something like this on multiple major branches, at least, at the time of writing, the `actions/checkout` repo doesn't do this. If we look at the most recent "v3" tag, `v3.6.0`, we can see [it's still using node16](https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/v3.6.0/action.yml#L89-L90), and the very first "v4" tag `v4.0.0` [is using node20](https://github.com/actions/checkout/blob/v4.0.0/action.yml#L92-L93). It's simply a matter of looking to see which tag(s) have the fix you're after, and in this case, all the "v4" tags onwards use `node20`.

Comment: I'm about to update mine to this. My problem is, since I'm new to all this, where would I find what `v*` to use? How did you find that `node20` is `v4`? I'd like to know so I can figure it out in the future myself since the warning, and the link it sends you to `https://github.blog/changelog/2023-09-22-github-actions-transitioning-from-node-16-to-node-20/`, doesn't seem to show this, unless the only way to know is by the link to the Github Docs you included and searching for `checkout` as I did. As I wrote this I found this `https://github.com/actions/setup-node`, would this be it? Thanks

Comment: I've edited it to hopefully make that clear. Lmk if it isn't. Beyond the use case of just updating to whatever the latest version is, which should work for most cases, you can just check which commits / tags have the particular change you're looking for. Nothing to do with using `actions/setup-node`, that's just _another action_ that itself has some versions that use `node16` and some that use `node20`, which is totally independent from which versions of node you might use that action to install.

Comment: Your edit made it much clearer for a noob like me. Thanks!